# How to specify Google Drive API spaces using CloudRail

Tags: android, cloudrail

I am writing an Android App to access Google Drive Photos via CloudRail service. I am able to authenticate to the Google account in question and see all my files/folders in the Google Drive, but I can't access photos from Google Photos.

While browsing through the Drive API documentation, it makes a reference to spaces, specifically 3 spaces are defined: drive, photos and allDataFolder.

Where do I specify the spaces that I am interested in? But default, the drive space is being accessed. Even though, I specifically specified scope for photos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
```

And when Google Authentication pages opens in the mobile browser, it states that my app wants to gain access to the user's Google Photos and I grant this access. But when calling CloudRail service to get children, no photos are visible

```
`googledriveChildren = mGoogledriveService.getChildren("/"); // returns goole drive top level files/folders


`googledriveChildren = mGoogledriveService.getChildren("/photos"); // generates a NotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already been down this path and achieved the integration - with the help/guidance from the folks at Cloudrail. You should note that my integration is limited to reading/downloading from Google Photos. I have not found any way to write/upload. Nor have I found any way of reading the album structure that can be set up in Google Photos.

First, you need to include the scope for Google Photos. I did this as follows:

```
 public static final String GOOGLE_PHOTOS_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly";

 private final AtomicReference<CloudStorage> googlephotos = new AtomicReference<>();


  List<String> scope = new ArrayList<>();
    scope.add(My_Constants.GOOGLE_PHOTOS_SCOPE);
    googlephotos.set(new GoogleDrive(context, google_client_id, "", Get.GetString(R.string.google_redirect_uri),
            Get.GetString(R.string.google_authentication_state), scope));
    ((GoogleDrive) googlephotos.get()).useAdvancedAuthentication();
```

You then need to build a Cloudrail advancedRequest to download whatever data you want. I download the metadata I require as follows:

```
CloudStrorage service = googlephotos.get();

   private void searchForGooglePhotos(final CloudStorage service) throws Throwable {
    GoogleDrive google_drive = (GoogleDrive) service;
    boolean more = true;
    String pageToken = null;
    while (more) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String query = URLEncoder.encode("mimeType='image/jpeg' and trashed = false", "utf-8");
        builder.append("/files?spaces=photos");
        if (pageToken != null) {
            builder.append("&pageToken=");
            builder.append(pageToken);
        }
        builder.append("&q=");
        builder.append(query);
        builder.append("&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,modifiedTime,description,size," +
                "imageMediaMetadata(height,rotation,width,time))");
        AdvancedRequestSpecification specification = new AdvancedRequestSpecification(builder.toString());
        AdvancedRequestResponse response = google_drive.advancedRequest(specification);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> resultObjectMap = (Map<String, Object>) response.getBodyJsonParsed();
        pageToken = (String) resultObjectMap.get("nextPageToken");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> filesObjectMap = ((ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) resultObjectMap.get("files"));
        for (Map<String, Object> fileObjectMap : filesObjectMap) {
            // process downloaded files
        }
        more = (pageToken != null);
    }
}
```

Subsequently in my app I use Glide to download the photos themselves when required. In the Glide DataFetcher I obtain the inputStream using:

```
if (model.getSourceRecord().isTypeGooglePhotos()) {
        AdvancedRequestSpecification specification;
        AdvancedRequestResponse response;
        if (model.getIsThumbnail()) {
            specification = new AdvancedRequestSpecification("/files" + model.getSourceId() +
                    "?spaces=photos&fields=thumbnailLink");
            response = ((GoogleDrive) service).advancedRequest(specification);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> parsed = (Map<String, Object>) response.getBodyJsonParsed();
            String link = (String) parsed.get("thumbnailLink");
            specification = new AdvancedRequestSpecification(link);
            specification.disableBaseUrl();
        } else {
            specification = new AdvancedRequestSpecification("/files" + model.getSourceId() + "?spaces=photos&alt=media");
        }
        response = ((GoogleDrive) service).advancedRequest(specification);
        input_stream = response.getBodyAsStream();
    } else {
        if (model.getIsThumbnail()) {
            input_stream = service.getThumbnail(model.getSourceId());
        } else {
            input_stream = service.download(model.getSourceId());
        }
    }
```

Here, "model" contains various info associated with each photo. The sourceId comes from the "id" downloaded:

```
String source_id = java.io.File.separator + fileObjectMap.get("id");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for providing such a detailed solution to the problem. Would've been nice, of course, if CloudRail simply had a "spaces" argument to one of their Service/Get functions.

Comment: How do you get the actual image URL to feed to glide? Is there another parameter that can be specified in the "files(id, name...)" something like path?

Comment: Thanks, @GaryKipnis. My understanding from Cloudrail is that the "spaces" is to specific to be included in their generic code and they have developed "advancedRequest" as a way to overcome the limitation.  I've edited my response to cover the feed to Glide.

Answer (score 1):

Would anyone arriving at this question / response please note that, as of mid Jan 2018, Google have "sunset" (sic) the photos space (spaces=photos above). This means that the above solution no longer works.

On the Google REST API documentation: "The photos space will sunset in early January 2018. Your users can continue to access Google Photos via the drive space by enabling the Google Photos folder in My Drive in the Drive client settings"

Ugh!